# The Ribbon Workbench Enable rule is not firing only when Group By is applied on an editable grid

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, powerapps, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am currently experiencing following issue and would greatly appreciate any assistance. Thanking you in advance.

**Issue Description:**

- The Ribbon Workbench Enable rule is not firing only when Group By is applied on an editable grid.
- The enable rule fires in all other cases, such as for single-record selection and even for multiple-record selection(Select All) when Group By is not applied.
- Surprisingly, it also works for single-record selection manually even when grouping is applied, but it does not work only for 'Select all' selection when grouping is applied.
- Note: The editable grid is formed by applying the Editable Grid component on a normal Subgrid.

**Detailed Explanation:**

- I've added an 'Approve' button to the editable subgrid using Ribbon Workbench.
- The visibility logic of the button is controlled by an enable rule, which involves a Custom Rule calling JavaScript logic.
- The visibility works seamlessly with both normal subgrids and editable subgrids, except in one scenario where Group By is applied to the editable grid.
- In the **working scenario**, when all records are selected in the editable grid and Group By is set to 'no Grouping,' the 'Approve' button is visible. Deselecting all records hides the 'Approve' button.
- However, in a **non-working scenario**, when all records are selected in the editable grid and Group By is set to 'Start Date,' the 'Approve' button should be visible, but it remains hidden. The issue lies in the enable rule not getting fired in this case, specifically when Group By is applied to 'Start Date.'